# Are there any available modern web parts to show existing “Prompted links”

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, modern-pages

Are there any available modern web parts to show existing “Prompted links” inside modern pages or any-other web part which can be used.

i want to add few clickable links/ images which will redirect the users to mailto: 
unfortunately am not able to achieve this in the modern UI

I tried this workaround by using Embed web-part and the end result is that 
it show the whole page components, such as the left side navigation, logo, upper ribbon menu.... is there anyway to hide them all and just display the prompted links.

Hero Web part cannot redirect users to mailto:

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'promoted links for modern pages' on Github,
[with info here](https://www.tonyishere.co.uk/promoted-links-web-part-for-modern-pages/). I have used it on our modern pages. I did find I had to take it apart and reconstruct it to make it look how I wanted so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert an Embed web part and use the following iframe code to embed the prompted links list page:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="1000" src="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/Lists/xxx/Tiles.aspx" scrolling="no" style="margin-top: -190px; margin-left: -200px;">
</iframe>
```

The result is like:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked as expected. However the Prompted link/list name shows up in the page.. 
How to hide the name of the list the way you have it in the screenshot above.

Comment: please append "isDlg=1" into the URL pf the src.